# Is there any way to direct to a page WHERE session is equal to something using C# and HTML

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am making a Categories catalog , and I am trying to do when you press on the "TV" link , it will take the session that I gave to the "TV" category and direct to all of the products of "TV".

Here is the example :

I have on my ACCESS database a table of categories with "categoriesId" and TV's id is : 1

Here is the HTML code :

```html
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Categories <span class="caret"></span></a>

                              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href=>Televisions</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Desktops</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">refrigerators</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">For Kitchen</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">air conditioners</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Washing machines and dryers</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Laptops</a></li>
                                
                                </ul>
                            
                            </li>
```

I want that When I press the "TV" , it will direct me into the Products.

Here is my C# code :

```
Session["category"] = 1;
    Response.Redirect("ShowProducts.aspx");
```

And in the Products page there is this code :

```
 int idCat = int.Parse(Session["Category"].ToString());


            dt = ProductsService.GetProductsByCategory(idCat);
            GridView1.DataSourceID = "";
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
```

I dont know what I should do in order to combine between the HTML code of the dropdown menu to C#.

Can you please help me ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: do `Session.Remove("UserID");Session.Clear();
            Session.Abandon();` during signout and check

Answer (score 1):

there is no problem with your code, the session is not expired so you can see the Sign in button again, close the browser and open it again, or resit the iis/iis Express and try again

also If you perform a signout, make sure that you remove the UserId session

```
Session.Remove("UserID")
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use JavaScript for this. A working sample is here, it shows you steps to follow to implement this.

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-clear-session-when-660c1e6b

Also you can use Session timeout to keep session alive for short intervals.

Answer (score 0):

it is not necessary that session variables need to be cleared during signout bcos session is not lasted..only signout is done..so it will be better to clear the session at the time of signout..

```
Session.Remove("UserID");
Session.Clear(); 
Session.Abandon();
```

during signout and check

Comment: please some details why this is an answer.

Comment: @Jayan it is not necessary that session variables need to be cleared during signout bcos session is not lasted..only signout is done..so it will be better to clear the session at the time of signout..